# Profit Maximization based on dynamix programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

I have been trying to solve this problem :
" You have to travel to different villages to make some profit.
In each village, you gain some profit. But the catch is, from a particular village i, you can only move to a village j if and only if and the profit gain from village j is a multiple of the profit gain from village i.

You have to tell the maximum profit you can gain while traveling."

Here is the link to the full problem:
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/practice-problems/algorithm/avatar-and-his-quest-d939b13f/description/

I have been trying to solve this problem for quite a few hours. I know this is a variant of the longest increasing subsequence but the first thought that came to my mind was to solve it through recursion and then memoize it. Here is a part of the code to my approach. Please help me identify the mistake.

```java
    static int[] dp;
    static int index;
    static int solve(int[] p) {
        int n = p.length;
        int max = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<n; i++)
        {
            dp = new int[i+1];
            Arrays.fill(dp,-1);
            index = i;
            max = Math.max(max,profit(p,i));
        }
        return max;
    }
    static int profit(int[] p, int n)
    {
        if(dp[n] == -1)
        {
            if(n == 0)
            {
                if(p[index] % p[n] == 0)
                    dp[n] = p[n];
                else
                    dp[n] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                int v1 = profit(p,n-1);
                int v2 = 0;
                if(p[index] % p[n] == 0)
                    v2 = p[n] + profit(p,n-1);
                dp[n] = Math.max(v1,v2);
            }
        }
        return dp[n];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used extra array to get the solution, my code is written in Java.

```
public static int getmaxprofit(int[] p, int n){
       // p is the array that contains all the village profits 
       // n is the number of villages
       // used one extra array msis, that would be just a copy of p initially
       int i,j,max=0;
       int msis[] = new int[n];

       for(i=0;i<n;i++){
           msis[i]=p[i];
       }
       // while iteraring through p, I will check in backward and find all the villages that can be added based on criteria such previous element must be smaller and current element is multiple of previous.

       for(i=1;i<n;i++){
           for(j=0;j<i;j++){
               if(p[i]>p[j] && p[i]%p[j]==0 && msis[i] < msis[j]+p[i]){
                   msis[i] = msis[j]+p[i];
               }
           }
       }
       for(i=0;i<n;i++){
           if(max < msis[i]){
               max = msis[i];
           }
       }
       return max;
    }
```